# Windows 7 enterprise lock out; only displaying admin user

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, login, user-accounts

I was trying to set up a home network on my Windows 7 admin machine, to do this, I needed to log in as an admin.

The problem is, I restarted the computer and now only the admin user is being displayed at log in, and I don't have the password. **How do I show my user without being able to log into windows?** I dont care about being able to log in as an admin anymore.

**How do I select the users that are on the welcome screen?**

Comment: You mind filling out your question to let us know what you did/tried so far?  Perhaps in the "Registry" department (since you tagged it as such)?  :) From what I can discern so far is that you simply rebooted (in anticipation of setting up the network as Admin) and now you are only presented with the Administrator account, and you don't know the password(?)

Comment: I've read in other places that I would be able to display other users at log-in were I to have access to the registry in windows. Maybe if there is a way to access the registry without logging in to windows, I would be able to display my non admin level user so that I could log into my computer. Sorry if that is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a valid administrator credential that is just not showing up you can use the Computer Management console from another Win7 machine to connect and administer it. This should allow you to change the admin password you are seeing. You can also create local user accounts and a bunch of other things that may be useful.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc780234(WS.10).aspx